# apply jquery to php generated pic list

Tags: php, jquery, html-lists, slideshow

I am triing to make tgis j query scrip that would act as a slide show, 
I generate pic list

by php
list stays verticle to the left
when I click on li item it becomes bigger and shifts to the same place wich ever li I click

now it just makes li items bigger.
what is needed to add/adjust

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div#dynamiclist_product table tr td img#thumb").click(function(){
$("div#dynamiclist_product table  tr td  img#main_pic").hide(); //hide prev pic that is loded automaticaly on product page
// enlarge when clicked
$(this).css("height","700");
$(this).css("width","500");
$(this).css("margin-top","170");//dont seem to work
$(this).css("margin-left","170");//dont seem to work

});});

//shrink back when other is clicked
$("img#thumb").click(function(){
$("img#thumb").css("height","160");
$("img#thumb").css("width","120");
$("img#thumb").css("margin-left","0");
$("img#thumb").css("margin-top","0");
});
```

Comment: you know you can do css like this:  `$(this).css({"height": 700, "width" 500, "margin-top":"170px", "margin-left","170px" });`.  Also if you are going to make multiple calls to `$(this)`, you are best off caching the variable: `var $this = $(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you'll need to add a "px" for the margin declares.
instead of

```
$(this).css("margin-top","170")
```

do

```
$(this).css("margin-top","170px")
```

maybe that's why it won't shift, sometimes you can try even with the !important tag, maybe it's been overwritten by some other css class.

**update**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="thumbnails" style="float:left;">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="...." /></li>
            <li><img src="...." /></li>
            <li><img src="...." /></li>
            //....
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="big pic">
        <p><img src="...:" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

maybe something like this. and replacing the img src of the big one with some jquery.

Comment: there is one more thing that is erong with my sliedeshow, thumbs and big pic move around when I click them I cant get this solved by seting absolute position how can it be fixed?

Comment: maybe instead of making the actual item bigger, have an item which you will replace with jquery is a better way of doing it. the more dirty way would be a nested <div> layer with some absolute positioning, or maybe a floating div.